How to find the weeknumber related to the latest value in a workload matrix?
I've created a workload chart that assigns production hours to projects for every production department. For a single production department, this looks like this:
Workload for a single department



Week
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38




1501926
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501925
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501924
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501929
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501930
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501928
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501927
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501937
34
27.2
6.8
6.8
3.2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501921
0
0
0
0
3.6
27.2
23.2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501953
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501950
0
0
0
0
0
0
0.5
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501951
0
0
0
0
0
0
30.7
68
68
68
68
68
68
46
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501958
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
22
68
68
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501944
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
67
11.5
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501955
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501942
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
56.5
44.1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501956
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1607654
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0.1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501959
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501940
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
20.8
68
68
35.9
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501954
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
26
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501957
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
6.08
68
14.2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501952
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
53.8
0
34
12.2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501945
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
55.8
47.9
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1607664
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0.1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501963
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
20.1
68
22
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1607648
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501962
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
46.1
33
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501960
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
35.1
11
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501965
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
24
0
0
0
0
0
0


1501964
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
33.1
17.5
0
0
0
0
0


1501968
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0



Workload for a single department
This means that this department will be done with all its projects in week 33. How do I return this value 33?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I've tried =lookup(2,1/(B2:AM33>0),B1:AM1) , but that return an error since =lookup only seems to work for 1 row and not the entire matrix.

For record kindly use Markdown_Table_Generator please don;t post images. Images are not suggested, you can read here the reasons-rules posting guidelines

You could try using the following:
=TAKE(TOCOL(B1:AM1/(B2:AM33>0),2),-1)




Or simply use AGGREGATE() function here:
=AGGREGATE(14,7,B1:AM1/(B2:AM33>0),1)


Or, try as mentioned in comments by VBasic2008 Sir
=LET(data,B2:AM33,TAKE(TOCOL(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(data))/(data>0),2),-1))


One more addition, if you specifically want to use LOOKUP() function, then you would need to use in the following way:
=LOOKUP(2,1/MMULT(SEQUENCE(,ROWS(B2:AM33)),N(B2:AM33>0)),B1:M1)



Great! The requirement could be titled "Index of the Last Column With a Number Greater Than Zero".

@VBasic2008 Sir, you are correct, but I am not changing the title. Let that leave with OP!

Of course, you won't since the formula corresponding to the mentioned title would be something like =LET(data,B2:AM33,TAKE(TOCOL(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(data))/(data>0),2),-1)) leaving the header row out of it.

@VBasic2008 Sir, is it any different. Because OP has already outlined the week number in the headers, then what is the point in using SEQUENCE() ? Ok, you dont want to take the header, so as to make it dynamic, alright. may i update the post with yours then?

I'm not criticizing anything, just observing ('loudly') and realizing how your great formula could be utilized in a different scenario.

@VBasic2008 Sir, even I am not, just asking because didnt realize you are trying to make it dynamic and independent

=MAX(IF(B2:G5<>0, COLUMN(B2:G5)-1))



Wrapping MAX(IF(hours, COLUMN(hours))) with parameters:
=LAMBDA(
    first_cell_for_dept,
    max_projects,
    max_months,
    LET(
        worksheet, 1:1048576,
        data_for_dept, first_cell_for_dept:
            INDEX(
                worksheet,
                max_projects +
                    ROW(first_cell_for_dept),
                max_months +
                    COLUMN(first_cell_for_dept)
            ),
        hours, DROP(data_for_dept, 1, 1),
        index_of_the_last_column_with_non_zero_hours, MAX(
            IF(hours, COLUMN(hours))
        ),
        project_completion_week_for_dept, INDEX(
            worksheet,
            ROW(first_cell_for_dept),
            index_of_the_last_column_with_non_zero_hours
        ),
        project_completion_week_for_dept
    )
)(B4, 100, 52)


